# Access denied exception handling in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I need to handling the exception "access denied" to redirect in a custom static html page. I read that in spring 6 exists a default access denied exception handler but this handler does not anything. Also I see that this redirection is being performed by a default filter in filter chain but I don't remember which filter does this work. Anyway I need to implement a custom exception handler for this exception in order to redirect in a custom page. How I could do this?

Comment: have you tried to add `request.exceptionHandling(ex -> ex.accessDeniedPage("/pageToRedirect"));` in `SecurityFilterChain` ?

Comment: I have set in object httpSecurity this .exceptionHandling((accessDeniedHandler)->accessDeniedHandler());

Comment: just try my approach and tell me if it meet your requirements.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the filter that is responsible for handling AuthenticationExceptions and AccessDeniedExceptions is called **ExceptionTranslationFilter** in case of **AccessDeniedException** it uses **AccessDeniedHandler** to handle it you can find more info [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-exceptiontranslationfilter).

for your case you will need to provide a custom implementation of **AccessDeniedHandler**

```
@Bean
AccessDeniedHandler customAccessDeniedHandler() {
    return (request, response, accessDeniedException) -> {
        // custom Handling here
    };
}
```

and sign it in SecurityFilterChain bean

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    ...
    .exceptionHandling(customizer -> customizer.accessDeniedHandler(customAccessDeniedHandler()));
    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: now i get this message in postman Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop http://localhost:8080/accessDenied

Comment: probably a mistake in your exception handling code "maybe share it"